# Distance between species in the Open Tree of Life

Tags: r, phylogeny

Greetings and Salutations,

I'm trying to find the relative distance to other species in the Open Tree of Life (OTOL). I'm using the `phytools` R package's `fastDist()` function to generate a count between branches of the tree. However, the function yields an error on ancestry.

**Debug info:**

```
Error in while (currnode != rt) { : argument is of length zero 
4 getAncestors(tree, sp1) 
3 fastHeight(tree, sp2, sp2) 
2 phytools::fastDist(tree, resolved_names_proper[i], resolved_names_proper[j]) 
1 get_distance(tree, species = c("Abies grandis", "Abies concolor", 
    "Abies lasiocarpa"))
```

**The offending code is:**

```
phytools:::getAncestors = function (tree, node, type = c("all", "parent")) 
{
    if (!inherits(tree, "phylo")) 
        stop("tree should be an object of class \"phylo\".")
    type <- type[1]
    if (type == "all") {
        aa <- vector()
        rt <- length(tree$tip.label) + 1
        currnode <- node
        while (currnode != rt) { #### error here
            currnode <- getAncestors(tree, currnode, "parent")
            aa <- c(aa, currnode)
        }
        return(aa)
    }
    else if (type == "parent") {
        aa <- tree$edge[which(tree$edge[, 2] == node), 1]
        return(aa)
    }
    else stop("do not recognize type")
}
```

**Tree Info:**

```
Phylogenetic tree with 304959 tips and 23328 internal nodes.

Tip labels:
    Leucas_martinicensis_ott9739, Leucas_deflexa_var_deflexa_ott531221, Leonotis_ocymifolia_var_schinzii_ott480842, Leonotis_ocymifolia_var_raineriana_ott480829, Leonotis_nepetifolia_var_africana_ott480834, Leonotis_nepetifolia_var_nepetifolia_ott480833, ...
Node labels:
    Chloroplastida_ott361838, Streptophyta_ott916750, , , , Embryophyta_ott5342313, ...

Unrooted; includes branch lengths.
```

Is it possible that the tree is not specifying the right node labels? (e.g. some node labels are empty?) For instance, `tnrs_match_names('Abies lasiocarpa')` returns a value, however, in the `tree$node.label` and `tree$tip.label` nothing is found.

The specific example that causes this error is given when I’m trying to find the distance between branches within the same genus (Abies). Currently, I use a tryCatch() to continue the process of building the matrix. However, it would be great to obtain some values.

**MWE:**

```
## Initialize Data

# Any package that is required by the script below is given here:
inst_pkgs = load_pkgs =  c("ape","phytools","R.utils","rotl")
inst_pkgs = inst_pkgs[!(inst_pkgs %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(inst_pkgs)) install.packages(inst_pkgs)

# Dynamically load packages
pkgs_loaded = lapply(load_pkgs, require, character.only=T)

# Grab the Chloroplastida tree
input_tree = file.path(tempdir(), "chloroplastida.tre.gz")
download.file(url="http://files.opentreeoflife.org/trees/v3subtrees/chloroplastida.tre.gz",destfile=input_tree)
gunzip(input_tree)

input_tree_final = dir(tempdir(), pattern=glob2rx("*.tre"),full.names=T)

# Now read in tree as an phylo object (from ape)
MyTree = read.tree(input_tree_final)

# List of Species
species = c("Abies amabilis","Abies concolor","Abies lasiocarpa")

# Look up "proper" names of species used in tree:
resolved_names = tnrs_match_names(species) # Finds the matching names...


## Output of resolved_names
##     search_string      unique_name approximate_match ott_id is_synonym is_deprecated number_matches
##1   abies amabilis   Abies amabilis             FALSE 876303      FALSE         FALSE              1
##2   abies concolor   Abies concolor             FALSE 876315      FALSE         FALSE              1
##3 abies lasiocarpa Abies lasiocarpa             FALSE  85998      FALSE         FALSE              1


# Make taxa names for querying the tree:
resolved_names_proper = paste(gsub(" ","_",resolved_names$unique_name),"_ott",resolved_names$ott_id,sep="")

## Output of resolved_names_proper
## "Abies_amabilis_ott876303"  "Abies_concolor_ott876315"  "Abies_lasiocarpa_ott85998"

# Single tests between species (can be used so you don't need to pre-calculate all species):
test_distance_ok = fastDist(MyTree,resolved_names_proper[1],resolved_names_proper[2])
test_distance_bad = fastDist(MyTree,resolved_names_proper[1],resolved_names_proper[3])
```

**Resulting distance matrix:**

```
                 Abies amabilis Abies concolor Abies lasiocarpa

Abies amabilis                0              4               NA
Abies concolor                4              0               NA
Abies lasiocarpa             NA             NA                0
```

**Edit**

Using the `rotl` package to construct the tree I receive:

```
resolved_names = tnrs_match_names(species)
tr = tol_induced_subtree(ott_ids=resolved_names$ott_id)
```

The tree gets built:

```
# tr
##    
## Phylogenetic tree with 3 tips and 2 internal nodes.
##   
## Tip labels:
## [1] "Abies_lasiocarpa_ott85998" "Abies_amabilis_ott876303"  "Abies_concolor_ott876315" 
##   
## Rooted; no branch lengths.
```

However, I lose the information on branches. Thus a new error:

```
 Error in phytools::fastDist(tree, resolved_names_proper[i], resolved_names_proper[j]) : 
  tree should have edge lengths. 
3 stop("tree should have edge lengths.") 
2 phytools::fastDist(tree, resolved_names_proper[i], resolved_names_proper[j]) 
1 get_distance(tr, species)
```

I've tried to directly obtain the chloroplast tree however the API will not return it. :

```
m = tnrs_match_names("chloroplastida")
tree = tol_subtree(ott_id = m$ott_id[1])
```

With error information:

```
Error in otl_check_error(req) : 
  Message: Requested tree is larger than currently allowed by this service (25000 tips). For larger trees, please download the full tree directly from: http://files.opentreeoflife.org/trees/
```

Hence, the direct download of the subtree above.

Furthermore, if I try to download and load the full draft v3 or v4 tree, I receive:

```
# Grab the entire tree
input_tree = file.path(tempdir(), "draftversion3.tre.gz")
download.file(url="http://files.opentreeoflife.org/trees/draftversion3.tre.gz",destfile=input_tree)
gunzip(input_tree)

input_tree_final = dir(tempdir(), pattern=glob2rx("*.tre"),full.names=T)

# Now read in tree as an phylo object (from ape)
MyTree = read.tree(input_tree_final)
```

Returns an error message of:

```
Error in if (sum(obj[[i]]$edge[, 1] == ROOT) == 1 && dim(obj[[i]]$edge)[1] >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a parser for the .tre file, the draftversion3 in fact, in JS, and I understand the question, but that code is completely alien to me and i will only explain the parsing and adding theory to get the distance...

The species and node are differentiated with certain signs like OTT00000 ott and a number and parentheses.

If i had to do what you asked in simple code, i could do it fairly easily, by counting forwards in the brackets to find the the number of species in between the two brackets, anc counting backwards to find the entire tree structre containing them...

Simple task, you just count ( +1 and ) -1 roughly speaking.

Once you have the entire tree of the two, it's relatively easy to backtrack across the nodes and Add together all distances from the two species until their shared tree node.

In termps of the extra functions provided by your code, i can't say what the functions are, but the base logic is very easy. Hope that helps to find the bug.

I use signs like OTT0000 type labels to differentiate between a species and a node.

Comment: incidentally, the latest tree version is 5.0 and it's here: https://tree.opentreeoflife.org/about/synthesis-release/v5.0